# Adding loading gif to NSAlert

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsprogressindicator, nsalert

I am wanting to add a loading gif to my NSAlert I have tried this but it does not seem to be working:

```
NSProgressIndicator * gif;
gif.style = NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle;
[gif startAnimation:self];

NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert setInformativeText:@"Please check your internet connection and try again."];
[alert setMessageText:@"Connection Error"];
[alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
[alert setAccessoryView:gif];
[alert runModal];
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the progress indicator is declared but not initialized.

Comment: `NSProgressIndicator * gif = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f)];` ?

Comment: the designated initializer is `initWithFrame:`

Comment: What's the problem. a)it doesn't appear b)it doesn't animate Update your question